# Umbraco error "Looks like there's still work to do"

Tags: asp.net, sql, content-management-system, umbraco

I am trying to publish Umbraco 4.7.0 site.

when i am trying to publish Node get this error.

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id', table 'hedronDB.dbo.cmsPropertyData'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

And when i see in browser i get "Looks like there's still work to do" this error.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are seeing the error in the database's [umbracoLog] error table?

Have you just migrated your site to a new server? If so, your umbraco.config file may be missing. This is usually why you see the "Looks like ..." message, because nothing has previously been published.

Also, check the permissions on the site to ensure that modify permissions have been given to the correct folders.

If none of these help, one of your doc types or pages may be corrupt, meaning that when a page or pages of a particular doc type are being saved, Umbraco thinks there should be a particular property on the doc type when there isn't.

Check the Umbraco logs in the database [umbracoLogs] table, and see if there is a reference to a particular doc type or page being saved. The solution here would be to recreate the offending doc type, and also recreate the pages from the doc type.

Aside from this, it is always worth checking or raising your issue at [our.umbraco.org](http://our.umbraco.org)

Finally, if possible I would very much advise upgrading to the latest version of Umbraco (currently v6.1.2) or at the very least v4.7.2 which is a patched version of the version you are using.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply. I have solved this problem by changing in database. My site is running well but Admin UI not showing Tree Nodes. any idea..?

Comment: Right click on the root node and select "Reload nodes". See if that works. The nodes are cached at application start.

Comment: Did reload nodes work? As it is not working for me. :(